# Interpolation of a str.join() via f-string

Tags: interpolation, python-3.7, f-string

Attempting to interpolate a str.join() operation:

```
>>> a = ["a", "b"]
>>> " ".join(a)
'a b'
>>> str = f"data -> {" ".join(a)}"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'
```

f-String does not allow interpolation of such operations?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Jack I eextect 'data --> a b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
a = ["a", "b"]
tmp = " ".join(a)
str = f"data --> {tmp}"
str
```

Output:

> 'data --> a b'

Comment: so I can't directly interpolate the str.join(), this is an expected behavior ?

Comment: @DreadAngel - Yes, f-strings expect a variable (`tmp`, in this case), not a method like `join()`.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing stopping you from using f-interpolation on the `join` method.

What is happening here is that you are ending your string with the second `"`. That causes syntax errors because only one `{` is present in your f-string. Use triple quotation marks or the single quotation so that the quote character can be included in your string.

```
>>> f"""data -> {" ".join(a)}"""
'data -> a b'
```

```
>>> f'data -> {" ".join(a)}'
'data -> a b'
```